# How to save bad invalid URLs that were typed in?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, sitemap

I am having a react-redux app and react-router v4 inside of app

Is there a way to catch all invalid URLs that were entered and save them to an array, like so `['https://mysite.co/progects', 'https://mysite.co/sometypo', 'https://mysite.co/something']`?

And then I want to send that data to server for building some redirects and some sitemap

Currently I have this:

```
 <Switch>
              {/* <Route path='/blog' exact component={Blog} /> */}
              <Route path='/projects/:id' component={ProjectDetails} />
              <Route path='/career/:id' component={CareerDetails} />
              <Route path='/apply-for-job' render={(props) => (
                <ModalWindow
                  {...props}
                  modalHeader='Apply form'>
                  <ApplyForm history={props.history} />
                </ModalWindow>
              )} />
              <Route exact path='/' component={withScrollPreservation(LandingPage)} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
              {/* <Route component={withScrollPreservation(LandingPage)} /> */}
            </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, say, to redirect someone, who typed `'/progects'` to `'/projects'` - well, that's nice UX, but your `Switch` block will be cluttered with tens of possible invalid urls.
As I see it, maybe you should add `<Redirect to='/main' />` at the bottom of your `Switch` so any invalid url gets redirected to Main component (or whichever you have) or to 404-Component.

If you still want to gather them, then instead of redirecting to Main or 404 Component, send them to specific `Error` component, where you can get the link via `this.props.history.location` and handle that link further in the component: send to server, set that url in local/session storage, etc.

Note that you'll need a way to store that data someplace which won't get cleared on unmounting.

In order to send users to that route you'll need to place that at the bottom of your `Switch`.

```
<Switch>
    ...{your routes}
    <Route component={Error} />
</Switch>
```

So actually all you need to do is handle those urls in your `NoMatch` component, like so

```
const path = this.props.history.location;
axios.post('your api', path);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your NoMatch component, you can have the logic to update unmatched/incorrect urls

```
class NoMatch extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     const { addNoMatchUrl } = this.props;
     // you might want to handle the duplicate url logic here too in addNoMatchUrl method
     addNoMatchUrl(this.props.location.pathname);
   }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      const { location, addNoMatchUrl } = this.props;
      if (location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
          addNoMatchUrl(location.pathname);
      }
   }
   render() {
      // render logic
   }
}

export default connect(null, {addNoMatchUrl});
```